# OS X Terminal Navigation with Emacs Keybindings

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal, navigation, key-bindings

Under the Linux Distros I have tested this on so far I can navigate the terminal with emacs keybindings:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> (beginning of line)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> (end of line)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> (previous command in history)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> (next command in history)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> (delete letter in front of cursor)

etc.

The entire emacs base navigation and base text manipulation scheme.

Is there a way to reproduce this for OS X. I looked into the settings of iTerm but they don't allow for it apparently.
The standard terminal has an extensive list of keybindings, but they hide behind cryptic codes like `\033OP`.

Comment: emacs key bindings are supported pretty much everywhere throughout OS X - and the default OS X Terminal with bash of course supports emacs key bindings - try it.

Comment: Well, you are partly right... least some of the emacs key bindings work. But for example <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> does not delete whole words, nor does <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> make jumping whole words. Apart from that I would rather keep using iTerm, because the standard terminal can't do other things iTerm can.

Comment: OK - since this is not a programming question you might get a better response by asking on http://Apple.stackexchange.com instead.